# Crash OnPageChangeListener on smallFragments

Tags: java, android, sdk

I've a problem with the following command in my android app:

`((android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)mSmallFragments.get(j)).onPageSelected(j);`

I get:

```
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yabeat.skmp3/com.yabeat.skipmp3.ui.YBTShopHomeActivity}:  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.yabeat.skipmp3.ui.YBTShopHomeActivity.updateViewPagerIndex(YBTShopHomeActivity.java:332)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.yabeat.skipmp3.ui.YBTShopHomeActivity.updateViewPager(YBTShopHomeActivity.java:321)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.yabeat.skipmp3.ui.YBTShopHomeActivity.createLargeFragments(YBTShopHomeActivity.java:347)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at com.yabeat.skipmp3.ui.YBTShopHomeActivity.onCreate(YBTShopHomeActivity.java:402)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-17 18:43:24.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

`mSmallFragments = new ArrayList();`

Problem is, that the app works on smartphone perfectly (4.1.2), but crashes on tablet (4.1.1).

If I remove: `((android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)mSmallFragments.get(j)).onPageSelected(j);`,

the app starts but doesn't show any ArrayList (only the main layout of the app).

Comment: So your code mSmallFragments = new ArrayList(); instantiates the variable, but where do you set mSmallFragments? Could you post that code? It looks like it isn't setting the value properly, hence the zero size of the ArrayList.